# Change in TableViewCell to take effect immediately

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a TableView with a custom cell. One of the subviews in the cell is a UIButton. When a user clicks on the button, I want the background to change. I get all of that working. But the problem is I cannot see the change until after I scroll the affected cell off screen and then return it on screen. But I want to see the change immediately, without the onscreen offscreen bit. How might I do that?

For a bit more about my implementation:

Inside the method `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I have the line

```
....
[cell.myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onMyBtnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then inside the `onMyBtnTapped` method is where I effect the color change.

So perhaps what I need to do is to redraw a specific cell from the parent view controller (?).

**a bit more**

I have gotten as far as getting the cell using `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`. But now that I have the cell, I don't know how to get it to redraw itself. I do this on android all the time. I am not sure how to do it on iOS.

Comment: Show the contents of `onMyBtnTapped:` and where you change the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reload the UITableViewCell on button click:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfGivenCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: I had a bug somewhere else. I fixed the bug and also added the wrapper. But I went back and check and it does work without the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place the following in the method.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: in the given scenario the beginUpdates and endUpdates are unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You can ask to redraw cell at visible rows:

```
NSArray *visibleIndexPaths       = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleIndexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```